# What CSS rule should I write in this special case?

Tags: html, css

I've been following a web tutorial to create a cascading menu for a system I am developing, it is ok but I have the following problem on my 3rd level menu layer:

When my cursor is above a list item of 2nd layer:
[image: When cursor is on <li> of the second layer]

When I move the cursor to the last layer, the link of the active list item changes it color, becoming invisible:

[image: Cursor above last layer]

The structure is somewhat like that:

```
...
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a> Cadastro <a/>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Produtos<a/>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>Adicionais<a/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Produtos<a/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>"Tamanhos"<a/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this is the css I'm using actually:

```
nav ul ul { 
  display: none; 
  background: #FFD200;  
  padding: 0; 
  width: auto; 
  position: absolute;  
  top: 100%; 
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 45px;
  font-size: 17x;
  color: #3F1312;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #3F1312;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 100%; 
  top:0;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  background: #FFD200; 
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #3F1312;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #FFD200;
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li a {
  color: #3F1312;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
  color: #FFD200;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block; 
  padding: 10px 45px;
  color: #3F1312; 
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul:after {
  content: ""; 
  clear: both; 
  display: block;
}
```

I need to know what css rule I have to apply to make it work. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Do those anchor tags not have a `href` attribute or did you just remove them for the purposes of posting here?

Comment: second option, actually I am developing using jsf and primefaces, so I just replaced my <p:commandLink> with anchors @Shaggy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set :hover property to the li element and not to "a" element.

see the difference below

```
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #3F1312;
}
/* Replace below code instead of Above one*/
nav ul ul li:hover a {
  background: #3F1312;
}


nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
  color: #FFD200;
}
/* Replace below code instead of Above one*/
nav ul li:hover ul li:hover a {
  color: #FFD200;
}
```

**Edit**

Checkout following rules, You will need to add these rules into your css to avoid third level menu problem

```
nav ul li:hover ul li:hover  ul li a{
    color: #3F1312;
    background: #FFD200;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li:hover  ul li:hover a{
    color: #FFD200;
    background: #3F1312;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but now all the 3rd layer <li> are painted brown even when they are not hover.. :((

Comment: Okey, Now I have solved your problem. check my answer edited section

Comment: Thanks bro :) Now it looks damn beatifull haha